# I trying use Griddle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

trying to use Griddle but it shows  'No results found'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';   
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadHeaders } from '../../redux/actions/header.actions';
import Griddle from 'griddle-react';
import HeaderRow from './HeaderRow';

class HeadersPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadHeaders();
  }

  render() {
    const { requestHeaders } = this.props;

    return (
      <DocumentTitle title={'Requests'}>
        <div className="container">
          <Griddle
            data={requestHeaders}
          />
        </div>
      </DocumentTitle>
    )
   }
 }

HeadersPage.propTypes = {
  requestHeader: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  loadHeaders: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

HeadersPage.defaultProps = {
  requestHeaders: [],
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  requestHeaders: state.headers.requestHeaders,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loadHeaders: () => {
    dispatch(loadHeaders());
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HeadersPage);
```

I tried to change to use bootstrap-react-table and html table and it works
perfectly fine
did I miss something in the code? 
please suggestions ...
or code sample ...

Comment: You are loading the data in ComponentDidMount(), so the first render is going to have no-data in it. The page should rerender when your data is added. That means you have a bug in your reducer.

Comment: Add the redux dev tools and make sure your state showing a diff. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Comment: Here is my reduce   function headerRequestSuccess(state, action) {
      return state.merge({
        requestHeaders: action.requestHeaders,
        loading: false,
        error: false,
     })
}; in debug I see props get populated

Comment: also checked state it gets changed

Comment: I am wondering if you there is an issue with the app instance of redux and the Griddle version of Redux. Did you try to create a HoC Container that has all the redux code and makes the display component that calls the React only Griddle component?